# What is the difference between Google Analytics - Universal Analytics and Google Analytics (Firebase)

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics

I am trying to implement Google Tag Manager for iOS app. I am relatively new to Google Tag Manager. In the dashboard, there are two options for Google Analytics namely Google Analytics - Universal Analytics and Google Analytics (Firebase).

What is the difference between those two? 
If I implement Google Analytics - Universal Analytics, will it report to both Firebase as well as Google Analytics?

Google is sunsetting Analytics services in October, is it better to go with Google Analytics (Firebase) or Google Analytics - Universal Analytics?

[image: Google Tag Manager]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the FB SDK since, indeed, google's sunsetting its GA support for free accounts as mentioned here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9167112?hl=en

That also means that you would have to go to Firebase and not Google Analytics for the data. And they've also changed the protocol for data tracking and reporting in FB.

If you want to report to both, you need to implement both FB and Analytics SDKs and duplicate the tags in GTM. That's how we're doing it now untill the GA part of it is not deprecated completely.